# Filter rows in an Excel Document based on specific name and extensions

Tags: javascript, excel, powershell

[Excel File for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ye8.png)
I am trying to filter the excel file based on name and extension. For example i would like to filter the Name column if there is a word that equals to Club and Monday and also .pdf if it contains Monday and Employee.
Can you please help me with this, I would like to use powershell if possible >
Thank you very much for your help and consideration.

I have tried below so far

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Results.csv"  | ? Name -like *Monday* or *Staff*| Export-Csv test.csv
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3385-excel-filter-exact-match.html

Comment: This looks like it looks for exact name on the column but i am trying to filter if it contains certain words like Monday or club or some other words . Thank you.

Comment: How about this? https://exceljet.net/formula/filter-text-contains

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help , I guess i will have to explain my questiona little better I am trying to filter excel files with thousands of rows based on certain names which is more than 5 and also based on extensions.

Comment: No problem, I don't know much about Excel - but I saw your post in the moderation queue and did some cursory googling. Not sure why a mod has downvoted your question - perhaps if you added more code that might help. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: A picture of text helps no one. It can't be copied/pasted. I for one will not spend time retyping out your example from image when you already have it in text. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to import the csv into a variable, then do your filtering off of that.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Results.csv"  

$filteredCsv = $csv | ?{ $_.Name -match "^Monday|^Staff" -and $_.extension -eq ".pptx" }

$filteredCsv | Export-Csv -NoClobber -UseCulture -Path test.csv
```